How to correctly type runnables in LangChain.JS?
I'm provided with the following fix type definitions:
export type RunnableFunc<RunInput, RunOutput> = (input: RunInput, options?: ({
    config?: RunnableConfig;
} & RunnableConfig) | Record<string, any> | (Record<string, any> & {
    config: RunnableConfig;
} & RunnableConfig)) => RunOutput | Promise<RunOutput>;
export type RunnableMapLike<RunInput, RunOutput> = {
    [K in keyof RunOutput]: RunnableLike<RunInput, RunOutput[K]>;
};

export declare class RunnableMap<RunInput = any, RunOutput extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>> extends Runnable<RunInput, RunOutput> {
    static lc_name(): string;
    lc_namespace: string[];
    lc_serializable: boolean;
    protected steps: Record<string, Runnable<RunInput>>;
    getStepsKeys(): string[];
    constructor(fields: {
        steps: RunnableMapLike<RunInput, RunOutput>;
    });
    static from<RunInput, RunOutput extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>>(steps: RunnableMapLike<RunInput, RunOutput>): RunnableMap<RunInput, RunOutput>;
    invoke(input: RunInput, options?: Partial<RunnableConfig>): Promise<RunOutput>;
    _transform(generator: AsyncGenerator<RunInput>, runManager?: CallbackManagerForChainRun, options?: Partial<RunnableConfig>): AsyncGenerator<RunOutput>;
    transform(generator: AsyncGenerator<RunInput>, options?: Partial<RunnableConfig>): AsyncGenerator<RunOutput>;
    stream(input: RunInput, options?: Partial<RunnableConfig>): Promise<IterableReadableStream<RunOutput>>;
}


export declare class RunnableLambda<RunInput, RunOutput> extends Runnable<RunInput, RunOutput> {
    static lc_name(): string;
    lc_namespace: string[];
    protected func: RunnableFunc<RunInput, RunOutput | Runnable<RunInput, RunOutput>>;
    constructor(fields: {
        func: RunnableFunc<RunInput, RunOutput | Runnable<RunInput, RunOutput>> | TraceableFunction<RunnableFunc<RunInput, RunOutput | Runnable<RunInput, RunOutput>>>;
    });
    static from<RunInput, RunOutput>(func: RunnableFunc<RunInput, RunOutput | Runnable<RunInput, RunOutput>>): RunnableLambda<RunInput, RunOutput>;
    static from<RunInput, RunOutput>(func: TraceableFunction<RunnableFunc<RunInput, RunOutput | Runnable<RunInput, RunOutput>>>): RunnableLambda<RunInput, RunOutput>;
    _invoke(input: RunInput, config?: Partial<RunnableConfig>, runManager?: CallbackManagerForChainRun): Promise<RunOutput>;
    invoke(input: RunInput, options?: Partial<RunnableConfig>): Promise<RunOutput>;
    _transform(generator: AsyncGenerator<RunInput>, runManager?: CallbackManagerForChainRun, config?: Partial<RunnableConfig>): AsyncGenerator<RunOutput>;
    transform(generator: AsyncGenerator<RunInput>, options?: Partial<RunnableConfig>): AsyncGenerator<RunOutput>;
    stream(input: RunInput, options?: Partial<RunnableConfig>): Promise<IterableReadableStream<RunOutput>>;
}

And now, I would like to correctly type (as in add typings to) my following piece of code (see aaa and ccc):
RunnableMap.from<aaa, bbb>({
    context: new RunnableLambda<ccc, ddd>({
      func: (input) => retriever.invoke(input.question).then(mergeDocsToString),
    }).withConfig({ runName: "contextRetriever" }),
    question: new RunnableLambda({ func: (input) => input.question }),
    chat_history: new RunnableLambda({ func: (input) => input.chat_history }),
  });


From my understanding, replacing ccc with {question: string; chat_history: string} should work, however, the types are not inferred (they remain any).
